# python - List of Lists into pandas dataframe including name of columns

Tags: pandas, list

I would like to transfer a list of lists into a dataframe with columns based on the lists in the list.
This is still easy.

```
list = [[....],[....],[...]]
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df = df.transpose()
```

The problem is: I would like to give the columns a column-name based on entries I have in another list:

```
list_two = [A,B,C,...]
```

This is my issue Im still struggling with.
Is there any approach to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Best regards

Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip` with `dict` for dictionary of lists and pass to `DataFrame`:

```
L= [[1,2,3,5],[4,8,9,8],[1,2,5,3]]
list_two = list('ABC')


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(list_two, L)))
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  1
1  2  8  2
2  3  9  5
3  5  8  3
```

Or if pass `index` parameter after transpose get columns names by this list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L, index=list_two).T
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  1
1  2  8  2
2  3  9  5
3  5  8  3
```

Comment: thanks a lot . thats what i was looking for:).